# UseEffect didn't work properly with affinda api

Tags: typescript, use-effect

Im not understand why i get 2 empty array firstm, and then get correct one

```
import  {AffindaCredential, AffindaAPI} from "@affinda/affinda";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const credential = new AffindaCredential("")
const client = new AffindaAPI(credential)

export function fetchCvList() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<any>([])
    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchdata = async () => {
        await client.getResume("grLaMgEb").then((result) => {
            if(result){
            setUser(result.data)
            }
        })
    }
    fetchdata().catch((err) => {
        console.log("An error occurred:");
        console.error(err);
    });
    },[])
    console.log(user)
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DXD9.png

Answer (score 0):

Rendering twice might be caused by React Strict mode. You can disable it by removing React.Strict wrapping your App component.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects